# Image Upload - Ckfinder Alternative for Ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder, file-manager, ckeditor5

I am looking for any alternative for image upload for ckfinder for ckeditor 5?
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html#full-integration

I am using simple upload plugin

Comment: Astonishing that there is no solution to this. Following just in case someone finds an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The simple upload adapter wasn't versatile enough for me.  I needed more control over the upload process, so I turned to making a custom uploader:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html

You just need to provide the upload "start", "abort", and "progress".  In fact, I'm not even doing the upload via javascript.  I'm using CKEditor5 in a Maui app so the upload is going to be started on the C# side.  HybridWebView is allowing Javascript to signal C# when to start.